# typeEror - o.map is not a function shows in react from hosted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, mern, vercel

I am making a MERN e-commerce project with redux.
I have hosted my backend in Heroku and my frontend is hosted in vercel .

> everything  running  fine from localhost but when I open hosted site
> then it shows "o.map is not a function" on console

Here is my project github link-

**Frontend**- https://github.com/arijitdas13105/Ashop-frontend-new

**Backend**- https://github.com/arijitdas13105/ashop-backend

M**y hosted website link** - https://ashop-frontend-99x2ayoh7-arijitdas13105.vercel.app/products

**My backend Product API** - https://ashop-server.herokuapp.com/api/products
let me know anything else need.

Comment: Please share full error. Most likely you didn't set an env var in heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you host in vercel, your JS code is minified with `react-scripts build` (You can see it in your `package.json`). This `o.map` is other variable in your code, probably the `products.map`. You can solve this issue using `products?.map` instead, so it will try to render the elements only when it has content.

If the data is not load and you don't know why, I recommend you to run it with `npm run dev` and figure out the reason (you can use `debugger` or `console.log`).

You can see the [Network Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INZHR.png) in your devtools to see what the backend is returning as well.